# How to trigger action using voice access?

Tags: react-native

I have created functions in react native to increment and decrement slider values for accessibility actions. I tried actions with voice access but its not working. Please take a look at my code.

```
                        <Slider
                            accessibilityLabel="Sliding line"
                            value={slide}
                            onValueChange={(value) => setSlide(value)}
                            
                            style={Styles.slider}
                            minimumValue={0}
                            maximumValue={1}
                            minimumTrackTintColor="#FFFFFF"
                            maximumTrackTintColor="grey"
                            accessible={true}
                            accessibilityActions={[
                                {
                                    name: 'increment',
                                    label: 'Increment'
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'decrement',
                                    label: 'Decrement'
                                }
                            ]}
                            onAccessibilityAction={(event) => {
                                switch(event.nativeEvent.actionName){
                                    case 'increment':
                                        handleIncrement();
                                        break;
                                    case 'decrement':
                                        handleDecrement();
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        console.log("unknown action");
                                        break;        
                                }
                            }}
                        />

const handleIncrement = () => {
        // Increment the value of the slider
        const newValue = slide + 0.1; // You can adjust the increment value as needed
        setSlide(newValue);
    };

    const handleDecrement = () => {
        // Increment the value of the slider
        const newValue = slide - 0.1; // You can adjust the increment value as needed
        setSlide(newValue);
        console.log("decrement")
    };
```

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Install the package @react-native-community/slider
2. Add the above code to your project and define states.
3. Install Google Voice Access and turn it on from Settings/Accessibility/Voice Access
4. Speak increment and decrement respectively.

I tried to perform increment and decrement she value of slider using voice access but it didn't worked. Please take a look at screencast : https://www.loom.com/share/Android-recording-15-Sep-2023-8b1b7039ddbf4aa482f3c6f876a32a23?sid=ab1d8a86-0a52-41b6-9384-4236bdd35a8b